# Event triggering on slide appearance

Tags: jquery, rstudio, r-markdown

When a slide comes into view, I would like to trigger an event, for example when we get to slide 2, a pop-up appears. I've tried a variety of jquery plug-ins with no success. In all my attempts the pop-up appears when the slides are initially loaded by the browser.

Here is my attempt using `jquery.appear`

```
---
title: "XXXX"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://morr.github.io/javascripts/jquery.appear.js"></script>

## Slide 1
Nothing to see here

## Slide 2
<div id="pop"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pop').appear(alert("Hi"));
</script>
```

I've also tried selectors such as, `#pop:visible` and `.current #pop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOSlides puts an object in your window namespace called `slidedeck` that can be used to programmatically control the deck. One approach might be to monitor the current slide, and run your code when it changes.

```
var curSlide = -1;
window.setInterval(function() {
  if (curSlide != window.slidedeck.curSlide_) {
     curSlide = window.slidedeck.curSlide_; 
     if (curSlide == 1) {
        // code to run when slide 2 appears goes here (curSlide_is 0-based)
     } else if (curSlide == 2) {
        // code to run when slide 3 appears goes here 
     }
  }
}, 100)
```

Comment: Your answer is works like a charm. I made a few minor tweaks, to your solution. In particular, changing `curSlide = -1` in case you want an event to occur on the title slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [bSlider](http://bxslider.com/) It has a callback onSlideAfter that Executes immediately after each slide transition. So you can make your logic for each slide what to do after it is in viewport and the transition is finished. You can check the rest of the [options](http://bxslider.com/options) and find out which one will suit you the best  :)

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/ksd36798/

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        // do funky JS stuff here
        //alert('Slider has finished loading. Click OK to continue!');
    },
    onSlideAfter: function () {        
        var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
        if(current == 1){
             alert('Show your pop up if slide number is 1');
        }
    }
});
```